# jack n poy program skips to the end after the first cin

Tags: c++, codeblocks

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int P1;
    int P2;
    int P, R, S;

    cout<<"This is a Jack n Poy game. \nPlease select R for Rock, P for Paper, and S for Scissors.";
    cout<<"\nPlayer one: ";
    cin>>P1;

    cout<<"\nPlayer two choice: ";
    cin>>P2;
    {
    if ((P1==R)&&(P2==R))
      {
        cout<<"\nInvalid Game";
      }
    else if ((P1==P)&&(P2==R))
      {
          cout<<"\nPaper Covers Rock";
      }
    else if ((P1==R)&&(P2==S))
      {
          cout<<"\nRock Breaks Scissors";
      }
    else if((P1==P)&&(P2==R))
      {
          cout<<"\nPaper Covers Rock";
      }
    else if((P1==P)&&(P2==P))
      {
          cout<<"\nInvalid Game";
      }
    else if((P1==S)&&(P2==P))
      {
          cout<<"\nScissors Cuts Paper";
      }
    else if((P1==R)&&(P2==S))
      {
          cout<<"\nRock Breaks Scissors";
      }
    else if((P1==S)&&(P2==P))
      {
          cout<<"\nScissors Cuts Paper";
      }
    else if((P1==S)&&(P2==S))
      {
          cout<<("\nInvalid Game");
      }
    else
      {
        cout<<("You have select an invalid selection.");

      }
    }
}
```

I'm new to c++ and this one is what I'm currently working on, I don't know what to do rn I tried changing the variables into char and string but it shows errors like `no match for 'operator&&'(operand types are 'std::__cxx11::basic__st...`

I already spent like 3 hours trying to do this but I just can't think of a solution, any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback in your question. As for the actual problem, P, Q and R are uninitialized variables. Furthermore, you should be using chars instead of ints.

Comment: this is the error traceback

Comment: no match for 'operator&&' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' and 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>')|

Comment: I arleady tried using string and char and it shows the error

Comment: That error traceback isn't produced by the code in the question, so either update the question with the right code or the right error traceback.

Comment: Im not sure if I understood that correctly, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing to uninitialized values:

```
   int P, R, S;
```

Your variables above are never initialized.

Maybe, just maybe, you'll want to use characters instead of integers:

```
char player1;
char player2;
//...
std::cout << "Enter move for player 1: ";
std::cin >> player1;
std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // Ignore rest of line.
std::cout << "Enter move for player 2: ";
std::cin >> player2;
std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n'); // Ignore rest of line.
player1 = std::tolower(player1);
player2 = std::tolower(player2);
if (player1 == player2)
{
   std::cout << "Same move, invalid game.\n";
}
else if ((player1 == 'r') && (player2 == 's'))
{
   std::cout << "Player 1 wins, rock beats scissors.\n";
}
//...
```

IMHO, your issues are that you didn't initializes variables you were using in comparisons and you are probably using the wrong data type (integers instead of characters).

**Edit 1:**
The statement `if ((P1 == R)` is comparing the **contents** of variable `P1` to the **contents** of variable `R`.  This is probably not what you were thinking of.  Maybe you were thinking comparing the contents of variable `P1` to a letter like `R`.

You could change your code to:
`if ((P1 == 'R') //...`
The single quotes are used to denote letters rather than variable names.